# How to Use Gravitons for Telekinesis?

Tags: internal-consistency, gravity, super-powers

I'd like to use the theoretical graviton particle to give some characters telekinetic abilities. My research so far is this:

• Gravitons are a theoretical particle in string theory that causes the bend in space-time we associate with the effects of gravity.

• Gravitons are massless and can travel at the speed of light.

• They are found wherever the effects of gravity are (a.k.a. in mass).

• The existence of gravitons may indicate that gravitational force is stronger than we usually observe because its effects are dispersed over other dimensions. (This is because gravitons are very, very small; much smaller than photons.)

Here are my sources:
[The Graviton and Superstring Theory: World Science Festival](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7opykja8jM) | [What Are Gravitons? by Don Lincoln: PBS.org](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/blogs/physics/2014/05/what-are-gravitons/)

My question is, even though gravitons might be stronger than we think because of the dimensional dispersal, would redirecting the gravitons' effects to a more singular dimensional direction generate enough strength to overcome the gravitational pull of an entire planet? Also, can this "telekinetic strategy" allow for manipulating the momentum of an object? I'm not interested in just levitating things, they need to be thrown.

Comment: Barring any other issues, if you're manipulating a gravitational field (by warping spacetime), you won't be able to single any one thing out.  You'll affect anything in the area you're changing stuff in.

Comment: @phiteros, actually the recent experiments proving that gravity can propagate as a wave implies that it may be possible to use phased outputs to create a linear path, or one of finite range. I don't know enough physics to know if a gravity wave can reasonably be offset enough to create a net force in a given direction, but there's at least one more piece that doesn't need to be handwaved outright.

Comment: @SeanBoddy You'll still get a region which you are affecting.  You wouldn't be able to point at say, a box, and only affect that one particular object.  If you wanted that, you'd have to have ~millimeter scale control.

Comment: @phiteros, you are correct, but to be fair, my solution already requires something like nano or picoscale time resolution in order to control phase differentials meaningfully. But you're right, the line and area of effect need consideration if OP gets detailed on science.

Comment: The nice thing about graviton-TK is that it could conceivably levitate a *liquid* - should that be something you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telekinesis is usually depicted as a mysterious unspecified psi power. Your question asks whether gravitons might be used create telekinesis. If gravitons could be generated on cue and in locations where they could move objects, preferably, at a distance this most certainly would look exactly like what we would expect telekinesis to look like.

If the statements in the previous paragraph seem rather torturous, there is method in my madness. If a mysterious unspecified psi force could either generate or focus flows or pulses of gravitons this could have an effect like a localized gravitational field.

For example, if a telekinetic wanted to move an object and they were able to project a psi power. This psi power could direct gravitons to attract the object to move in a specified direction. This could towards or away from the telekinetic. Or up or down, even left or right, and north or south or whatever direction the telekinetic wants.

These graviton-powered localized gravitational effects would be both temporary and strong enough to overcome the usual physical forces keeping the object stationary (this includes gravity and friction).

The conceptual weakness of most versions of telekinesis assume psi forces somehow move objects in an unspecified, mysterious way. Now if telekinesis can act as an intermediate mechanism to control, create or focus gravitons, then if telekinesis can manipulate gravitons the gravitons in turn will manipulate material objects. This will make them move. It can even be made to exert turning moments of force on objects to make them bend and break.

In summary, if telekinesis can manipulate gravitons then gravitons can manipulate matter. This is precisely what telekinesis does. Telekinesis by gravitons is a plausible mechanism for a telekinetic psi power.

Answer (score 2):

If gravitons exist (which is not proven or even certain at this point), the only way to manipulate then gravitational field (which is still what you're trying to do) is to manipulate the energy density (which includes mass) in space.

In (extreme) principle you could manipulate the energy density to space time locally and variably.  However to do this you would use *other* forces (e.g. EM fields) not directly using gravity.

The practical reality is that if you could use other forces to manipulate gravity locally, it would be far easier to use the same forces to directly affect the object you want to move.  This would also require less energy to do as gravity is a relatively weal force (and this won't change because you try adding extra dimensions where gravity is strong, as this won't affect the energy required to affect matter in your "everyday" dimensions - it just means you're wasting lots of energy in other dimensions).

Incidentally, levitation is harder than throwing.

Throwing something requires nothing more that a single directed impulse.  It requires limited precision.

Levitation requires a continuous application of precise force to counteract normal gravity.

You might picture this as the difference between kicking a plate away and balancing one on a stick.  Which is harder ?

Comment: Could you please edit the phrase " the only way to manipulate then gravitational field" (in paragraph 2, line 1, sentence 1)? I don't quite understand what you're try to say. Otherwise, it's nice answer.